# PendingIntent not opening activity

Tags: android, kotlin, widget, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to create a widget that has a button which will open my app whether or not it's already open and have been able to confirm that `views.setOnClickPendingIntent` works by trying to open a URL but when I try to launch a `PendingIntent` that is setup to open my app, it doesn't work. Here is the code I use:

```
val intent = Intent(context, LauncherActivity::class.java)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.title, pendingIntent)
```

I've already tried different flags, but open to hear any suggestions!

EDIT: I've tried launching other activites from the widget which seemed to work fine, but unfortunately opening the launcher does not. Is there something I need to set in the manifest to allow opening the launcher?

This is how the launcher is setup in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LauncherActivity"
    android:noHistory="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And an activity that works:

```
<activity android:name=".parent.ParentActivity" />
```

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't working? It may be that the `Activity` is started, but crashes. Check your logcat (don't filter the logcat as you might miss an important message).

Comment: Is the behaviour different if your app is already running or not?